# Hibernate Criteria - Return parent records that have child records

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

All,

I'm probably over-analyzing this problem, but...

Given table "A" with two one-to-many relationships "A1" and "A2", return all records in table "A" that have at least one child record in either table "A1" or "A2"...

I'm not necessarily interested in knowing *what* the child data is, but rather that I just have child data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a `Restrictions.isNotEmpty()` criterion:

```
List<A> r = s.createCriteria(A.class)
    .add(Restrictions.or(
        Restrictions.isNotEmpty("a1"), 
        Restrictions.isNotEmpty("a2"))).list();
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know this. It's probably not available in NHibernate.

Answer (score 0):

You need a subquery, using DetachedCriteria:

There is an [example in Ayende's Blog](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/10/28/QueryingCollectionsInNHibernate.aspx). I don't have currently the time to work it out.

Answer (score -1):

I think that this example will help you.  It is written in t-sql, but should be easy to follow whatever platform you are using.

```
/*Create data structures*/
CREATE TABLE Parent (  
  ParentId      INT         NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY  
  , ParentName  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE ChildA (  
  ChildAId      INT         NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY  
  , ParentId    INT         NOT NULL    CONSTRAINT FK_ChildA_Parent FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Parent(ParentId)  
  , ChildAName  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE ChildB (  
  ChildBId      INT         NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY  
  , ParentId    INT         NOT NULL    CONSTRAINT FK_ChildB_Parent FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Parent(ParentId)  
  , ChildBName  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)

/* Insert four parents */  
INSERT INTO Parent VALUES (1,'A')  
INSERT INTO Parent VALUES (2,'B')  
INSERT INTO Parent VALUES (3,'C')  
INSERT INTO Parent VALUES (4,'D')  

/* Insert two children for A */  
INSERT INTO ChildA VALUES (1,1,'a')  
INSERT INTO ChildB VALUES (1,1,'a')

/* Insert one child for B */  
INSERT INTO ChildA VALUES (2,2,'b')

/* Insert one child for C */  
INSERT INTO ChildB VALUES (2,3,'c')

/* This select stmt returns A with children in both child tables, B with a child in ChildA, and C with a child in ChildB, but no D. */   
SELECT  *  
FROM    Parent p  
WHERE   EXISTS (select 1 from ChildA a where p.ParentId = a.ParentId)  
OR      EXISTS (select 1 from ChildB b where p.ParentId = b.ParentId)
```